# Syntax error expr

Tags: bash, expr

Why does the following returning a syntax error:

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
echo `expr match "$stringZ" 'abc[A-Z]*.2'`
```

This works on my ubuntu machine but when I try it on my mac running OS X 10.9.4 I get `expr: syntax error`?

Comment: Have you tried using `echo $(expr match "$stringZ" 'abc[A-Z]*.2')`?

Comment: @TomFenech same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bash version difference.  The `:` syntax works on my OSX 10.9.4 machine (which has bash 3.2.51, not very current):

```
echo `expr "$stringZ" : 'abc[A-Z]*.2'`
```

Comment: Online documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expr.1.html

Answer (score 3):

`expr` is quite old-fashioned. On newer bash you may prefer to use the more modern regular expression syntax:

```
re='abc[A-Z]*.2'
[[ $stringZ =~ $re ]] && echo ${#BASH_REMATCH}
```

The `=~` operator is available since bash version 3.0. For maximum compatibility across older versions of bash, [it is recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions) to store the pattern to be matched in a separate variable and expand it without quotes. Successful matches are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. If capturing groups are used, each group will be stored as a separate element in the array.